# How do I use (or mimic) document.getElementById() on a page loaded from WordPress database?

Tags: plugin-development, pages, jquery, javascript

I am trying to bind javascript function calls to specific pages in a plugin I'm developing. All of the javascript functions and calls are located in IIFE's, one for the admin side, and one for the public side.

On the admin side, my Tools page is loaded using an `include` statement, and I can use either jQuery or `document.getElementById()` to create the bind. However, when I tried the same approach on the public side page, which I've placed in the database, things don't work.

In the current form, I have the code `<body data-bind="PublicInterface">` at the top of the public page (in the database).

In the Javascript:

```
if ( document.body.getAttribute('data-bind') === 'PublicInterface' ) {
    alert ('Found it!');
};
```

The error provided is `TypeError: document.body is null`

I have also tried approaching this with jQuery using `<div id="home-search" data-bind="PublicInterface">` in the document, where the Javascript is:

```
if ( $('#home-search').length ) {
    alert ('Found it!');
};
```

This fails silently.

As I can get both approaches to work with the admin side, I started thinking the problem stems from how WordPress loads pages.

If this is the case, how can I bind javascript to a page loaded from the WordPress database?

Comment: Whether a page is loaded from a WordPress database or not would have nothing do with whether or not JavaScript works. This looks like you're just running scripts in the head before the body or any elements have loaded. That's a JavaScript issue, nothing to do with WordPress or databases.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that the javascript is in two separate IIFEs, one for the public side, and one for the admin side. I assume from your comment then that you've done bindings like this? If so, what is not correct in my call?

Comment: It told you, you appear to be running it before the DOM has loaded. Where are these scripts executing? In `<script>` tags, or from a file? Where in the DOM are they?

Comment: The IIFEs are in separate files. As I said, the same code blocks work on the admin side, but don't work on the public side. The only difference I see is that one page is loaded with an straight `include` while the other uses WordPress code. But I'll go back and study the code more. I take it from your responses that your answer to my question is that I can in fact bind javascript to a page loaded from the WordPress database, and that it is done in exactly the same manner as it would be done with a non-WordPress page?

Comment: Exactly, make sure your JS is being loaded in the footer. If you update your question with the code being used to load the files it might be easier to help, and more on-topic.

Comment: Got it! I am using the WordPress Plugin Boilerplate and the default behavior for enqueuing the script is to not have it in the footer. I changed that setting to true, and it appears to work. Thank you.

Comment: @tim.rohrer, please make a proper answer and accept it ;)

Comment: I'll do that @MarkKaplun. Although not directly part of the original question, I'm still confused about why the default behavior for `wp_enqueue_script` worked for the admin page where the page was `included`, but had to be changed for the page loaded by WordPress core. If someone sheds some light on that, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to register and enqueue javascript contained in a separate file. The default behavior is for `wp_enqueue_script()` is to load the script before the `</body>` tag, and apparently WordPress pages require the script to be loaded in the footer. As pointed out in the comments, the clue to this problem with the loading sequence was in the `TypeError` that the `document.body` was null.

Once the `wp_enqueue_script()` `$in_footer` option was set to `true`, the original javascript ran as expected and binding to the page occurred. This change was only required for the public side page, and was not required for the admin side page `included` into WordPress.